# bash script average of two values

Tags: bash, scripting, iperf

I have a bash script that runs iperf and outputs the average bandwdith ie 3.80 Mbits/sec. What i'd like to do is get this output as an average of the connection speed.

So if I have a 10Mbit connection i'd like to know what 3.80 Mbits/sec is of that so output something like

```
3.80 Mbits/sec 38%
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

My script does

```
iperf -c 1.1.1.1 >> /tmp/iperf.log
echo -e " \t $(awk '/Bandwidth/ {getline}; END{print $7, $8}' $iperflog"
```

which returns

```
 3.80 Mbits/sec
```

i'd like it to return

```
 3.80 Mbits/sec 38%
```

Comment: The problem is that `bash` does not support floating point, so you need a language or tool that does.  Simplest is probably `awk`, but there are many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example with `awk`:

```
user@host:~# echo "3.80 Mbits/sec" | awk '{printf "%s %s%%\n", $0, $1/(10.0/100)}'
3.80 Mbits/sec 38%
```

To apply to your script just add the `awk` part after your command:

```
echo -e " \t $(awk '/Bandwidth/ {getline}; END{print $7, $8}' /tmp/iperf.log" | awk '{printf "%s %s%%\n", $0, $1/(10.0/100)}'
```

Comment: I get the following error `awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%s %s%
")
        FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1`

Comment: When you copy and paste the command exactly as above in the command line?

Comment: @Lurch found the mistake, try again please.

Comment: excellent thank you, i have updated my original post with my code, how would I fit yours with mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42958/discussion-between-lurch-and-chaos)